# Cannot fetch the value of a mysql alias

Tags: mysql

I have the following code:

```
$query = " SELECT distance, outcodepostcodes.lat,     outcodepostcodes.lng     
FROM ( SELECT $table.*, outcodepostcodes.lat, 
outcodepostcodes.lng , outcodepostcodes.lat*3 AS distance 
FROM $table     
LEFT JOIN outcodepostcodes ON UPPER($table.postcode)  =      outcodepostcodes.outcode ) AS x
WHERE $where_no_and AND (hide='0' OR hide IS NULL OR hide='') 
AND distance <= 20 ORDER BY rent $reihenach LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage ";
```

When I do a:

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) 
{
$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
etc, etc;
$distance=mysql_result($result,$i,"distance"); }
```

$distance is empty

Any help appreciated

Comment: too many `distance` words in one select for me :D can't even read it properly, I'd change the name first